# createQueryBuilder with resultMapping issue doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have dql like this :

```
            $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb
            ->select('c.login, c.char_name,c.id,c.sex,c.pvpkills,c.pkkills,c.online,c.online_time,c.last_access,MAX(cs.level) as lvl,sub.name,sub.clan_id')
            ->from($this->target,'c')
            ->leftJoin('CharacterSubclass','cs','WITH','c.id = cs.char_id')
            ->leftJoin('clan','cln','WITH','c.clan_id = cln.id')
            ->leftJoin('ClanSub','sub','WITH','cln.id = sub.clan_id')
            ->where('c.clan_id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id',$id)
            ->groupBy('c.id')->orderBy('lvl','DESC');
            $rs = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The result isn't in object-form.

```
array(100)=>{[0]=>array(8){['id']=>'axb' [name]=>'fyz'} [1]=>array{....}}
```

I tried  with result-mapping but no hope,waste time.
Is there anyway to do that???
i want the result like this :

```
array{[0]=> object(Character)=>{[id]=>'abc' [name]=> 'fyz'....} [1]=>object(Character){...}}
```

Answer (score 1):

on doctrine examples if are two different entities: [Doctrine Native Query Example](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples)

```
<?php
// Equivalent DQL query: "select u from User u join u.address a WHERE u.name = ?1"
// User owns association to an Address and the Address is loaded in the query.
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('User', 'u');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'name', 'name');
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('Address' , 'a', 'u', 'address');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'address_id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'street', 'street');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'city', 'city');

$sql = 'SELECT u.id, u.name, a.id AS address_id, a.street, a.city FROM users u ' .
       'INNER JOIN address a ON u.address_id = a.id WHERE u.name = ?';
$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, 'romanb');

$users = $query->getResult();
```

if you have a entity like this, you can use a serializer I'm using [jms Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle):

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="login", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $login;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="char_name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $charName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sex", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $sex;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pvpkills", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $pvpkills;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pkkills", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $pkkills;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="online", type="boolean")
 */
private $online;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="online_time", type="datetime")
 */
private $onlineTime;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_access", type="datetime")
 */
private $lastAccess;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lvl", type="integer")
 */
private $lvl;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="clan_id", type="integer")
 */
private $clanId;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set login
 *
 * @param string $login
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setLogin($login)
{
    $this->login = $login;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get login
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLogin()
{
    return $this->login;
}

/**
 * Set charName
 *
 * @param string $charName
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setCharName($charName)
{
    $this->charName = $charName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get charName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCharName()
{
    return $this->charName;
}

/**
 * Set sex
 *
 * @param string $sex
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setSex($sex)
{
    $this->sex = $sex;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sex
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSex()
{
    return $this->sex;
}

/**
 * Set pvpkilss
 *
 * @param string $pvpkills
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setPvpkills($pvpkills)
{
    $this->pvpkills = $pvpkills;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get pvpkilss
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPvpkilss()
{
    return $this->pvpkilss;
}

/**
 * Set pkkills
 *
 * @param string $pkkills
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setPkkills($pkkills)
{
    $this->pkkills = $pkkills;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get pkkills
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPkkills()
{
    return $this->pkkills;
}

/**
 * Set online
 *
 * @param boolean $online
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setOnline($online)
{
    $this->online = $online;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get online
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getOnline()
{
    return $this->online;
}

/**
 * Set onlineTime
 *
 * @param \DateTime $onlineTime
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setOnlineTime($onlineTime)
{
    $this->onlineTime = $onlineTime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get onlineTime
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getOnlineTime()
{
    return $this->onlineTime;
}

/**
 * Set lastAccess
 *
 * @param \DateTime $lastAccess
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setLastAccess($lastAccess)
{
    $this->lastAccess = $lastAccess;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lastAccess
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getLastAccess()
{
    return $this->lastAccess;
}

/**
 * Set lvl
 *
 * @param integer $lvl
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setLvl($lvl)
{
    $this->lvl = $lvl;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lvl
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getLvl()
{
    return $this->lvl;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set clanId
 *
 * @param integer $clanId
 *
 * @return Test
 */
public function setClanId($clanId)
{
    $this->clanId = $clanId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get clanId
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getClanId()
{
    return $this->clanId;
}
```

SO after execution of the query you can serialize the array to the object like this.

```
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
$objects = $serializer->fromArray($data, 'array<NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\Test>');
```

You will have a object that you want

Comment: i am using `createQueryBuilder`. That's why i am looking for  how to use with `resultmapping`.

Comment: I'm be ussion ResultSerMapping a few times I didin't find a option to use QueryBuilder, other option is take the sql and the parameters from querybuilder and do a normal sql.

Comment: $result = $qb->getQuery()->getSQL();

   $param_values = '';  
   $col_names = '';   

   foreach ($result->getParameters() as $index => $param){              
            $param_values .= $param->getValue().',';
            $col_names .= $param->getName().',';
   }

Comment: could you please give me more detail? I can't get a picture from your code in my head. Thanks.

Comment: The Idea is convert the Query Builder to SQL from getSQL, get the parameters and execute a native query and mapping.

Comment: could u please use with `createQueryBuilder()`. That's why i made question.

Comment: with `createQuery` then i could do it already. But i don't want.

Comment: I add a work around to your problem not mapping but using a serializer I'm edit my first response.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i don't think i would use it. i would like to reduce library using on my project. I looked at jms Serializer. It's good but  i could use it here. Sorry.